# .NET to web crypto interoperability padding issue

Tags: .net, encryption, aes, padding, webcrypto-api

I'm attempting to encrypt some data in .NET (using C#) and then decrypt it in the browser using the web-crypto APIs (and vise-versa). For some reason the encrypted output of each side differs slightly. The browser output has an additional 16 bytes appended to the end of the data and I can't find what's causing it.

The .NET code that does the encryption is:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
{
    using (var aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        var key = new byte[] { 168, 126, 39, 25, 51, 65, 246, 41, 228, 56, 66, 237, 5, 8, 211, 102, 250, 16, 99, 12, 204, 14, 162, 126, 166, 140, 15, 124, 194, 186, 141, 111 };
        var iv = new byte[] { 188, 227, 223, 253, 171, 64, 82, 150, 10, 130, 159, 79, 68, 134, 192, 50 };

        using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
        using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            return msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The JavaScript code is as follows (assume missing variables are correct):

```
function encrypt(data, key) {
    window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "AES-CBC",
            iv: Uint8Array.from([188, 227, 223, 253, 171, 64, 82, 150, 10, 130, 159, 79, 68, 134, 192, 50]);
        },
        key,
        data 
    )
    .then(function(d){
        var encryptedBytes = new Uint8Array(d);
        // encryptedBytes had an additional 16 bytes added to the end of it for the same input.
        console.log(encryptedBytes);
    });
}
```

The encrypted bytes match the ones from the C# version, but will have an extra 16 bytes added onto the end. Is this a padding issue? From the docs I can find, it seems PKCS7 is the correct padding mode to use.

I thought the browser version might be appending the initialization vector to the end of the data, but I checked and it didn't match up.

Trying to decrypt the data encrypted by the C# code just errors with odd exceptions in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MarkovskI's answer, while not the final solution, helped me discover the root cause. The issue ended up being that the `CryptoStream` wasn't finished writing the data to the `MemoryStream` due to how my `using` statements were arranged.

There are two possible solutions.

1) Call `FlushFinalBlock()` before returning the `MemoryStream's` array.

```
csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
return msEncrypt.ToArray();
```

Just calling `Flush()` (which I had tried) did not work. This makes sense since it needs to be sure all data has been written before calculating and writing the padding.

2) Nest an inner `using` statement to be sure the `CryptoStream` has been disposed of before calling reading the `MemoryStream`. This interally must call `FlushFinalBlock()` in the `Dispose` method:

```
using (var aes = new AesManaged())
{
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    var key = new byte[] { 168, 126, 39, 25, 51, 65, 246, 41, 228, 56, 66, 237, 5, 8, 211, 102, 250, 16, 99, 12, 204, 14, 162, 126, 166, 140, 15, 124, 194, 186, 141, 111 };
    var iv = new byte[] { 188, 227, 223, 253, 171, 64, 82, 150, 10, 130, 159, 79, 68, 134, 192, 50 };

    using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
    using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        return msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AES requires the length input to be multiples of 16, so you must apply padding, this is where PKCS#7 comes in and the extra data comes from, which is a problem in the .Net implementation. If you want to remove the padding you need to remove it from the final block, you can do that using the following:

```
public class NoPaddingTransformWrapper : ICryptoTransform
{
    private ICryptoTransform _mTransform;
    public NoPaddingTransformWrapper(ICryptoTransform symmetricAlgoTransform)
    {
        _mTransform = symmetricAlgoTransform ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(symmetricAlgoTransform));
    }

    public bool CanReuseTransform => _mTransform.CanReuseTransform;

    public bool CanTransformMultipleBlocks => _mTransform.CanTransformMultipleBlocks;

    public int InputBlockSize => _mTransform.InputBlockSize;

    public int OutputBlockSize => _mTransform.OutputBlockSize;

    public int TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount, byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset)
    {
        return _mTransform.TransformBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount, outputBuffer, outputOffset);
    }

    public byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
    {
        if (inputCount % _mTransform.InputBlockSize == 0)
        {
            return _mTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount);
        }
        byte[] lastBlocks = new byte[inputCount / _mTransform.InputBlockSize + _mTransform.InputBlockSize];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(inputBuffer, inputOffset, lastBlocks, 0, inputCount);
        byte[] result = _mTransform.TransformFinalBlock(lastBlocks, 0, lastBlocks.Length);
        Debug.Assert(inputCount < result.Length);
        Array.Resize(ref result, inputCount);
        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _mTransform.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think my .NET code needs to add 16 bytes of data, not remove it. Or perhaps I'm missing something here. Doesn't setting the padding mode in the .NET code force it to add the padding? And also, wouldn't adding 16 bytes mean that it is already a multiple of 16?

Comment: I think your answer is solving the reverse problem from what I needed, but it has gotten me closer. The problem is that the C# code isn't adding the padding when it should. For a sample input set of data that is 108 bytes, we should be adding 4 bytes of padding, but despite setting aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7, that data is never added.

If I manually add the padding in the .NET code, the output matches the web version. This seems odd though so there must be something I'm missing with the .NET API.